# Installing Mongo DB and get this error when start

Tags: mongodb

I have followed this steps and install MongoDB in my Linux mint and finally run this command

```
mongo --host 127.0.0.1:27017
```

But got this error after run this command.

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.18
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
2017-12-21T13:16:20.693+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2017-12-21T13:16:20.693+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:231:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

I have already run this command also

```
sudo service mongod start
```

But after this command,

```
 mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: 
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-12-21 13:35:28 IST; 6s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 4891 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (cod
 Main PID: 4891 (code=exited, status=100)

I found many solution but did not get it resolved. Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `mongod` service is running locally

`sudo service mongod status`

and if it's not, run `sudo service mongod start`

If that doesn't help, try this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo mongod --repair
```

and run `service mongod start` again

**EDIT**

Try changing permissions in the mongodb folder

```
cd /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb *
```

Also, If that doesn't help, run this

```
sudo /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
```

and tell me the output (If it works is doesn't solve your problem, the service startup still needs to be fixed, just curious)

Comment: I have tried this command "sudo service mongod status". It is showing Active: Failed

Comment: Great, try using `sudo service mongod start` and if it errors please edit your question and post the output there

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check. It is still showing the same thing.